# Load the saved positions of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that saves the positions of all the enemies but I can't load them into the loadData function.
Here is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class SaveSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F5))
        {
            SaveData();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F9))
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }

    public void SaveData()
    {
        GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");

        SavedData savedData = new SavedData
        {
            enemies = gameObjects,
            enemiesPositions = gameObjects.Select(enemy => enemy.transform.position).ToArray()
        };

        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(savedData);
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedData.json";
        Debug.Log(filePath);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData);
    }

    
    public void LoadData()
    {
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedData.json";
        string jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        SavedData savedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<SavedData>(jsonData);
    }
}

public class SavedData
{
    public GameObject[] enemies;
    public Vector3[] enemiesPositions;
}
```

Thanks to this script, I save the positions of each enemy but I can't load them. How can I do this?

I try this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < savedData.enemies.Length; i++)
        {
            savedData.enemies[i].transform.position = savedData.enemiesPositions[i];
        }
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not working"? Which part isn't working? Do you have any error logs? The more details you can give the better we can answer

Comment: When I use this loop, there is no error message but nothing happens. Even though I saved and reloaded my games, all my enemies returned to their initial point.

Comment: Have you tried adding a debug log so you can see what your actual position values are? Or if your loop is even running to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

As much as i know, gameobjects can't be saved that way. You should use unique IDs for each objects. For example if each object has different names, you can use them for SavedData like this;

```
public class SavedData
{
    public string[] enemiesNames;
    public Vector3[] enemiesPositions;
}
```

After loading, you should find each object in the scene with same names/IDs and set
their positions.

```
for (var i = 0; i < savedData.enemiesNames.Length; i++)
{
  GameObject.Find(savedData.enemiesNames[i]).transform.position = savedData.enemiesPositions[i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this changes the whole backup system. What needs to be changed and how?

Comment: Are you spawning enemies on runtime or are they prebuild/placed by hand into the scene?

Comment: They are placed into the scene.